# How do I prevent a scaled up View from overlapping the actionbar?

Tags: android

I have a view that I scale up like so:

```
vpImagePreview.findViewWithTag("pos" + 0).setScaleX(1.15f);
vpImagePreview.findViewWithTag("pos" + 0).setScaleY(1.15f);
```

On some screens, when scaled up, this view hides a small part of the ActionBar behind itself. How do i make the ActionBar always be on top?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
activity.toolbar.bringToFront();
```